# Norm in the cyclotomic field

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, roots-of-unity

Let $F = \mathbb{Q}(\xi_p)$ be the $p^{th}$ cyclotomic field.

What is the norm of $N(1 + \xi_p)$?

I’ve figured out that $N(1-\xi_p) = p$, as this can easily be seen from the minimal polynomial of $\xi_p$.

I’m stuck on how to find $N(1+\xi_p)$, though.

Comment: If $f(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $\xi_p$, then $f(x-1)$ is the minimal polynomial of $1+\xi_p$. Or, if you prefer, $\pm f(-x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $-\xi_p$.

Comment: Yet another way. $1+\xi_p=(1-\xi_p^2)/(1-\xi_p)$, so if you also know the norm of $1-\xi_p^2$, then...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume $p$ is a prime. If $p\ne 2$ then
$$N(1+\xi_p)=\frac{N(1-\xi_p^2)}{N(1-\xi_p)}=1$$
since $1-\xi_p^2$ is a conjugate of $1-\xi_p$.

Comment: Beat me by 4 seconds :-)